# Is the Shimano TX-505-8 rear hub compatible with 11-speed cassettes?

Tags: hub, compatibility, drivetrain

After recently changing my bike's entire transmission, I noticed that when on the smallest sprocket, the chain is rubbing against the rear derailleur (right next to where the derailleur is attached to the frame). My mechanic tried to slowly push it outwards a bit (the derailleur), telling me it probably got bent during some mechanical shock. I accepted it as it was, although I never hit the bike and I'm always careful, regardless if I'm on the street or in the woods, trailing.
Still, even after moving the derailleur towards the exterior, the chain is still rubbing against the derailleur, when on the smallest sprocket. I've done some research and my rear hub seems to only be compatible with 8-9-10 speed cassettes (it's a Shimano Tourney TX-505). Do I have to change my rear hub?
Conversely, while pedaling, there's a constant sound coming from the rear hub/cassette (simillar to the sound the ratchets make when not pedaling but of a different pitch). It's there regardless of which speed / combination I'm using but it's different in intensity (louder on some speeds while more subdued on others). Can this also be caused by the hub's (in)compatibility with an 11-speed drivetrain? The chain, derailleurs, crankset and shifters are all 3x11 speed.

Thank you!

Edit: Some photos have been uploaded [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFC78.jpg).

Comment: Are you talking about MTB or road 11 speed? MTB is compatible with the regular freehub, road is not.

Comment: Can you please [edit] in a photo or two showing the problem?  I started an answer based on chain rubbing the frame because the 11 speed cassette is wider than the 10 speed cassette,  and this might be incorrect.   Try and get a good clean photo, well lit, showing exactly where its rubbing.

Comment: @Criggie i've edited the post with a link to a few pictures. I know the difference between road and MTB hubs and i know that, in theory, even a lowly TX-505 should fit an 11-speed cassette. What's bothering me is that everywhere i've looked, it's specified that this hub is only compatible with 8-9-10 speed cassettes and chains. Other hubs do have a 11-speed HG-X chains compatibility tab so maybe there's that?

Answer (score 2):

Shimano says the Tourney level [TX-505-8 hub](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/tourney-tx800/FH-TX505-8.html) is compatible with 8-10 speed cassettes.

Mountain bike 11 speed cassettes fit in on a '10 speed' freehub, because the larger inner sprockets can extend off the inner end of the freehub and not interfere with the hub and spokes. On road bikes where cassettes have narrower ranges and smaller inner sprockets the freehub has to be wider (although some wider range road cassettes do fit on 10 speed freehubs).

So, an 11 speed cassette should fit on this hub. It may be installed incorrectly. Did you put any kind of spacer on the freehub with the cassette?

Comment: The current 11 speed cassette has replaced a 9 speed one. As far as i can tell, no spacer was put there (but i will double-check with my mechanic, once i take it back).

Comment: @Chris did you place 11 speed cassette? What were the results? what model cassette did you put? On my hub the model is FH-TX505 (without 8 at the end) is it the same? Shimano compatibility chart says it's not compatible with 11 speed cassette and in the same time the specifications from the link above says it's compatible for 11 speeds MTB... So you are the key to all this confusion.

Comment: Also this [guy](https://youtu.be/2Dw2_uP8zKo?t=256) shows it fits